# What are the differences between the standard game and Deluxe?

Tags: cities-skylines

Steam lists two versions of this game: *Cities: Skylines* and *Cities: Skylines Deluxe Edition* (and also the standard to Deluxe upgrade pack). Unfortunately, it doesn't actually say what the difference is between them. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a listing for it on [Green Man Gaming](https://www.greenmangaming.com/games/cities-skylines-deluxe-edition/) that lists the Deluxe assets as follows:

Included in the Deluxe Edition are 5 In-game historical monuments from around the world, the games original soundtrack as well as a digital art book.

Five in-game items include:

Statue of Liberty

Eiffel Tower

Brandenburg Gate

Arc de triumph

Grand central terminal

Original Soundtrack: This Original Soundtrack includes 14 unique tracks mixed from the ambient music of the game, allowing you to enjoy the wonderful music whenever you want.

Digital Art book: See the concepts behind the buildings! The book features almost a 100 hand drawn concepts of the game various buildings and the story behind each.

[image: deluxe assets]

Comment: I also found the answer and this points to the [main game link](http://store.steampowered.com/app/255710/Cities_Skylines/)

Comment: Wait, so is the in-game music the same between the two? The deluxe just comes with an extra copy of it you can play separately to the game? Other sources were seeming to claim the regular game doesn't come with a soundtrack.